# JFrame not appearing when using while loop and Executor

Tags: java, swing

it's my first post here. I already looked for an answer and those that I found did not help me.
I wanted to have a simple TCP Server running with use of FutureTask.
It should be waiting for a client until the button is pressed and the executor is stopped. 
My window App is appearing only when I don't use the while loop.

Could anyone help me please?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

   ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
   TCPServer tcpServer = new TCPServer(15002, true);
   FutureTask<Integer> ft = new FutureTask<>(tcpServer);
   pool.execute(ft);

   final JFrame frame = new JFrame("TCP Server");
   final JLabel print = new JLabel("Program is executing!");
   final JToggleButton switchButton = new JToggleButton("Cancel");
   final JLabel status = new JLabel("Waiting for connection");
   int i = 0;
   while (!switchButton.isSelected() && !ft.isDone()) {
     i++;
     String temp = "Waiting for connection... " + i + " s.";
     status.setText(temp);
     int sleep = i*1000;
     Thread.sleep(sleep);
   }
  switchButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
  @Override
  public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
    if(e.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
      status.setText("Cancelled");
      pool.shutdown();
    }
   }
 });
 frame.getContentPane().add(print, BorderLayout.NORTH);
 frame.getContentPane().add(switchButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
 frame.getContentPane().add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
 frame.pack();
 frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
 frame.setVisible(true);
 }
}
```

Comment: It´s executing within the same thread as your `gui`. Your `JToggleButton` will be initialized unselected, and whatever `TCPServer` is, it will probably be not "done", so it seems you have no chance to have an "end" in your loop and as though will never get to the point of your `frame.setVisisble...` (as you never leave the loop)

Comment: Thank you, all I needed is to move the while loop down. I feel stupid, thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wait for connection, before you call frame.setVisible(true);

You need to reorder the initialization like:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.FutureTask;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ExecutorService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        TCPServer tcpServer = new TCPServer(15002, true);
        FutureTask<Integer> ft = new FutureTask<>(tcpServer);
        pool.execute(ft);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("TCP Server");
        final JLabel print = new JLabel("Program is executing!");
        final JToggleButton switchButton = new JToggleButton("Cancel");
        final JLabel status = new JLabel("Waiting for connection");
        switchButton.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
            @Override
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                    status.setText("Cancelled");
                    pool.shutdown();
                }
            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().add(print, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frame.getContentPane().add(switchButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.getContentPane().add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        int i = 0;
        while (!switchButton.isSelected() && !ft.isDone()) {
            i++;
            String temp = "Waiting for connection... " + i + " s.";
            status.setText(temp);
            int sleep = i * 1000;
            Thread.sleep(sleep);
        }

    }
}
```